# Delete my Worldbuilding account

Tags: support

I would like to delete my WorldBuilding account. The "Delete Profile" button isn't there. What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

You've already posted and voted on the site, so they can't remove you automatically from the database.

You need to go on [this form](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/contact) and select the option "I need to delete my user profile". The SE team will contact you (to see the details, I guess).

I'm sorry this didn't work out.

Comment: I'm getting a "this operation cannot be performed on a meta site; please continue on the main site." I have tried removing the meta. from the url and the form.

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I also want my account deleted. I already requested my account to be deleted and it was scheduled for deletion yesterday.

Comment: Account deletion is not an automated process. For users above a certain level of participation on a site, a community manager (not a mod) needs to review the account and manually delete it. With your 142 posts on the main site, that will take time. [This (now deleted) user](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/why-is-my-account-still-not-deleted) on Interpersonal Skills was similarly frustrated with deletion not being immediately. I don't remember exactly how long it took for their account to eventually be deleted but you can trust that it will happen.

Comment: From the help center: We have a system in place that examines the impact of removing a user's votes. If the user has cast a large number of votes, deletion will be held up so staff may consider preserving the votes prior to the deletion. The decision is at the staff's discretion and cannot be reversed after the deletion has taken place.

Comment: If it takes more than a week I will do like two more bounties. But this account should have been deleted days ago.

Comment: Active bounties might complicate the review process. They're assessing the impact of removing your votes and other reputation changes.