# How to delete my account with all my questions?

Tags: support

For personal reasons I need to get rid of my account. I need help in this.

This website is not for me. It's time to say goodbye.

How can I delete my account forever step by step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete my Worldbuilding account](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/delete-my-worldbuilding-account)

Comment: Damn i feel like a prisioner now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in [Delete my Worldbuilding account](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/delete-my-worldbuilding-account), you can delete your account using the "contact us" link.

However (and the reason I'm not marking this question as a duplicate of that), you also said "with all my questions".  Once you post content to Stack Exchange it belongs to the community.  In particular, deleting questions that people put effort into answering isn't very nice to the people who did that work.  If a question *isn't* valuable to the community -- for example, it's downvoted and closed -- we might consider deleting it anyway, but those would need to be considered on a case-by-case basis.

When your account is deleted, all your remaining posts will show as being from a generic user number (like on the linked question here).  Your name won't appear on them.

Comment: No fair,This is just unfair,But anyways,Im not going to post a single thing here ever again.

Comment: @AlexMyrmidon it's not meant to be unfair or punative; we're trying to balance the needs of *all* our members.  If you want to ask for specific questions to be deleted, let us know.  Particularly, as I said, questions that didn't go over well could possibly be deleted.  We just can't give a blanket "yes"; we need to look at individual cases.  So let us know which ones you care most about and we'll review.

Comment: @AbandonedAccount this was in the rules when you created your account. If you didn't accept rules then, you shouldn't have registered or post anything in the first place.